# Installing Pentaho PDI on Oracle VM

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, pentaho, kettle

I am taking online classes in business intelligence and for couple of assignments we are asked to install Pentaho PDI (I am trying to install pdi-ce-6.1.0.1-196). I am using Oracle VM and Oracle DB Developer VM already installed. 
Honestly, I am lost with instructions on how and where to install PDI? Class forum is pretty unresponsive. Can anybody help me with this? Please, take into consideration that I am very new to VMs and Pentaho.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Do yo have a Java install? Open a command prompt and type `java -version` to find out. If you don't, that's the first thing to install (latest version of Oracle Java).

Comment: Yes, I do have java . version 1.8.0_91

Comment: What have you done to install PDI, and what were the results? You're on Oracle VM ... is that Oracle Linux then?

Comment: I have downloaded pdi-ce-5.0.1-stable.zip version instead of the latest since that was in the instructions. I have not done anything after that. I just want to know what I am doing. I have Oracle DB VM linux, that is correct. Where do I install PDI? Under Oracle DB or do I create a new VM?

Comment: If you're only installing PDI (Kettle), just unzip the zip file in any location. I used /opt on my Ubuntu install. Then do `sudo chmod a+x spoon.sh` to make the startup script executable. Optionally, create an icon on your desktop via the normal method your distro provides. Note that there is a spoon icon file you can associate with the shortcut (spoon.ico I think). After starting for the first time, create a repository for jobs and transforms. Here's a very minimal link: [Installing Kettle](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/01.+Installing+Kettle).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I ran ./spoon.sh and it seems like it is working but per course requirements I have to install more programs in under Pentaho so I have completed all of the steps.

Comment: Actually, I am still dealing with this program. I have downloaded pentaho biserver-ce-5.3.0.0-213.zip and pivot4j. At the end I have to ping  http://localhost:8080/ which I have changed to 8081 because when I ping 8080 it goes to Oracle somehow. Anyways, 8081 looks way different than what I see on the instructions. Page itself looks really weird. It should show pentaho/login; however. I don't see anything like that. I dunno what to do anymore. Instructions are awful.

Comment: Ask a separate question for that.

Comment: I did and here is the link if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794601/pentaho-home-the-requested-service-is-not-available