# /pentaho/home The requested service is not available

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, pentaho

I am trying setup pentaho biserver and followed all of the steps necessary;however, this is the error I am getting when I try to connect to localhost8081 (I have changed the port to 8081 from 8080 because oracle is using 8080). I am doing this on ORACLE DB VM so it is a linux environment.
This is the error from the website:

```
HTTP Status 404-/pentaho/home
type status report
message/pentaho/Home
```

Here is the catalina.out log file:

```
description The requested service is not available.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Jun 13, 2016 12:12:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jun 13, 2016 12:12:39 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8081
Jun 13, 2016 12:12:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1549 ms
Jun 13, 2016 12:12:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 13, 2016 12:12:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
Jun 13, 2016 12:12:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor pentaho.xml
```

Can anybody help please? I have been working on this for last 4 days just to logon to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: I would have left this as a comment, but apparently don't have the rep to leave comments on the OP yet.

What version of Pentaho are you trying to deploy? What version of Java are you running in conjunction with Pentaho? It is important information to include, as this can help those of us trying to answer your question rule out a few things before answering.

Pentaho and Java versions often clash - many people are running more recent Java versions than Pentaho supports - for instance, Pentaho 5.1 only supports the version 1.7 release of Java.
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0D0/160/000

Comment: the sentence *"(...) only supports version X release of Java"* doesnt make any sense. 1.8 is *(of course)* backwards-compatible to nearly every JRE-version in existence *(with exceptions, of course)* - and it has been like that for ages. If this pentaho-bullcrap actually refuses to start with JRE8 just because it was written with JRE7 in mind ... well ... thats one piece of software you better should avoid ... just saying. In that case, it should be hardwired to obsolete/deprecated classes and thats a pretty solid sign of horrible programming.

Comment: You know what in the course it was asking us to install an older version of pentaho biserver-ce which I have tried and didn't work. Then, I have decided to install the latest version of Pentaho which works with JRE8 and voila. Everything is working now. This was a pretty nasty setup. Thank you so much for responding to my post.